# Emacs, Zen-Coding mode, and Putty

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, emmet

I use emacs via Putty and since Putty doesn't send certain key combinations to the remote console I generally need to re-bind them to other key combinations.

After installing the amazing [Zen-Coding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/) [mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ZenCoding) I had some trouble with the preview it generated; I couldn't get it to insert the output it was previewing. I got around this with the following keybindings:

```
(global-set-key "\M-\r" 'zencoding-expand-line)
(global-set-key "\M-]" 'zencoding-preview-accept)
```

However, what I'd *like* to do is be able to hit `M-RET` again when the preview is open and have it insert the output.

My emacs-lisp-fu is **extremely** weak, however.

Is there a way I can test whether the preview is open and capture/bind another `M-RET` keypress?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the key that does preview accept in this function at line 585 or so, like this:

```
(defvar zencoding-preview-keymap
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map "\M-\r" 'zencoding-preview-accept)
    (define-key map [(control ?g)] 'zencoding-preview-abort)
    map))
```

Comment: Is editing the elisp mode file itself a better idea than putting overrides in your .emacs?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the buffer specific key bindings instead of the global ones.